# "Graphical" stats for DropBox linux CLI?

Tags: linux, dropbox

Is there an `htop` style DropBox monitoring software package? I find myself running `dropbox status` a lot to see where my synchronization state stands.

I'd rather just keep open a terminal with my running stats. Is there such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to run `watch dropbox status`, which will automatically run the command (by default) every couple seconds. I do it when I want to keep an eye on my dropbox.